# Build a bucket-list histogram from scratch in Python

Tags: python, histogram

I'm working on [Think Python](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/), and there's an [exercise](http://www.greenteapress.com/thinkpython/thinkCSpy/html/chap09.html) where you're to write a function that does the following:

- take as arguments: `L` (a list of numbers) and `n` (and int)
- return a histogram in the form of a list of `n` sub-lists

  - each sub-list represents sub-division of the range covered by the numbers in `L`, and contains an int that represents how many elements of `L` fell in that sub-division

So we're looking at a range of numbers, chopping that range into `n` equal buckets, and building a histogram with those buckets. The section preceding this exercise shows how you'd build such a function when dealing with lists of random floats in the interval [0.0, 1.0). It looks at where an element falls in that interval (which is simply it's value), multiplies that by `n`, and converts to an int (truncating in the process). This yields an int in [0, n), which is the appropriate bucket index.

The difference here is that we're not working in a predetermined (and convenient) interval. Here's what I came up with. I'd like to know if there's a more elegant way to do this. I calculated my interval as `max(L) - min(L)`, but had to add a little extra to it, otherwise the largest element in `L` gets an index of n (which is out of range), when it should instead get n - 1. I called the little extra `extraBit`.

```
def histogram(L, n):
    hist = [0] * numBuckets
    minVal = min(L)
    maxVal = max(L)
    extraBit = .0000000000001
    interval = (maxVal - minVal) + extraBit

    for i in L:
        placement = (i - minVal) / interval
        index = int(placement * numBuckets)
        hist[index] = hist[index] + 1

    return hist
```

Is there a prettier way to do this?

Comment: prettier would be indentation.

Comment: Can you be specific? I'll break it up for better readability, but I don't know if that's what you mean.

Comment: someone else fixed it yesterday...

Answer (score 2):

I wrote my own last week:

```
def frequency_count(itt, nr_bins, minn=None, maxx=None):
    ret = []
    if minn == None:
        minn = min(itt)
    if maxx == None:
        maxx = max(itt)
    binsize = (maxx - minn) / float(nr_bins) #man, do I hate int division

    #construct bins
    ret.append([float("-infinity"), minn, 0]) #-inf -> min
    for x in range(0, nr_bins):
        start = minn + x * binsize
        ret.append([start, start+binsize, 0])
    ret.append([maxx, float("infinity"), 0]) #maxx -> inf

    #assign items to bin
    for item in itt:
        for binn in ret:
            if binn[0] <= item < binn[1]:
                binn[2] += 1        
    return ret
```

This one allows you to take a slice of the values instead of the whole range. It fixes your overflow problem with the addition of -inf->min and max->inf catchall buckets. I dont know if this is acceptable for you.

Comment: That would fix my overflow problem, but one of the goals of this exercise (which I should have mentioned) is to avoid having to loop through all the bins for each element of itt that you inspect. That way you can perform len(itt) iterations instead of len(itt)*len(ret).

Comment: Interesting. I will have another look at it since I now need to assign points to tiles which is the same problem but then in 2d. Keep you posted.

Comment: I had this problem for a tech phone screen w/ Zalando today and my implantation looks pretty much the same.